# How do i read only png files saved in Documents Directory and add it toan Array?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I am downloading a zip file to Documents directory of iPhone and then Unzipping it there.Now i want to read only png files from there and load it into an Array.How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do something like this...

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:documentDirectory];

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *tString in dirContents) {
         if ([tString hasSuffix:@".png"]) {
               [array addObject:string];
     }
}
```